# "socket hang up" error occurs when sending ReportState requests - Node.Js

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I am using a Node.js client to integrate with Google Smart Home.

The following error occurs when the number of requests to Google Smart Home API exceeds 100~150 per minute.

```
FetchError: request to https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:reportStateAndNotification failed, reason: socket hang up
```

It seems like we hit the API rate limit, but I saw the docs say: "Default limit of 6,000 requests per 60 seconds per Actions project”, though Our Node.js client never post such a lot of requests.
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/quotas

Does anyone know any clues to solve this?

Libraries

- @googleapis/homegraph: 3.0.2
- Nodejs: 18.4.0

Answer (score 0):

The QPS limit we listed there is for sending HTTP POST requests to our servers. When you hit the 6000 quota limit this way, you will start to get HTTP Error 429 responses to your http requests, with a “run out of resources” error description.

Looks like your issue is on the Node.js side, with the app you use. We recommend to take a look at your code to see at which step your HTTP requests fail to send (or get a response) for your messages.